# Error occurred during import the content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, import

Error occurred during import the content in wordpress also i can extend the time to 300 sec. Plese tell me the solution. You can see the error given below which is occure during the importing content time.

WARNING] Failed to import product_tag Bags [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag black [WARNING] Failed to import pa_color Dark [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag dress [WARNING] Failed to import product_type external [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag floral [WARNING] Failed to import product_type grouped [WARNING] Failed to import pa_color Light [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag marble [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag one piece [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag shorts [WARNING] Failed to import product_type simple [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag slub [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag stripe [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag swimsuit [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag t-shirt [WARNING] Failed to import product_type variable [WARNING] Failed to import product_tag white [WARNING] Failed to import product_cat Bags [WARNING] Failed to import product_cat Denim [WARNING] Failed to import product_cat Dresses [WARNING] Failed to import product_cat Hats [WARNING] Failed to import product_cat Shoes [ERROR] Failed to import "fashion" (Media) [ERROR] Failed to import "fashion" (Media)
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kane em\wp-includes\class-wp-image-editor-gd.php on line 200

Comment: so you did the ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes in your php.ini file?

Comment: yea  i already execution time but still getting error